# Warning .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Failure in @ExceptionHandler in my Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, controller-advice

I am trying to under why am getting this warning from my general exception handler method.

I am running SpringBoot version **2.6.1**. and using @ControllerAdvice to handle exceptions globally.

This is the general exception handler method:

```
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  @ResponseStatus(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
  public ExceptionResponse handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
    return sendResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request, "Runtime Exception", ex.getMessage(), ex);
  }
```

[image: Log message]